# RxJS catchError with replace strategy not publishing response to the subscriber

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I am new to RxJS and trying to understand catchError operator with replace strategy.

In my interceptor I have the below code

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): any {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      tap(res => console.log(JSON.stringify(res))),   // printed 
      catchError((error, o) => {
        console.log("Error received: " + JSON.stringify(error))   // printed
        return this.httpClient.get<any[]>("/backend/data");
      }),
      retry(3)
    );
  }
```

My backend Service calls a backend service which throws an error which results in catchError operator being called. The operator is returning a new observable, and the alternate backend service is being called as expected, as I can see in the console that the response is getting printed. But the response is not being received by the subscriber method on the backend service class.

```
this.httpClient.get<any[]>("/backend/data1").pipe().subscribe(v => console.log(v))   // not executing/called
```

But when I move the catchError operator to the backend service later, it is working as expected and I can see the response being printed from the subscribe method. Below is the modified code.

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): any {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      tap(res => console.log(JSON.stringify(res)))   // printed
    );
  }

this.httpClient.get<any[]>("/backend/data1").pipe(
      catchError((error, o) => {
        console.log("Error received: " + JSON.stringify(error))   // printed
        return this.httpClient.get<any[]>("/backend/data");
      })
    ).subscribe(v => console.log(v))   // printed
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?